# how we get a closure these set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have  some questions

how we get a closure these set from any interval of real number

For example (1,2),[3,6],(8,10],(2,infinity),(-infinity,4]?

what is the formula closure in metric space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your curiosity might be solved by proving that $(a,b]$ has $[a,b]$ as its closure. Other cases are similar.

1. If $p<a$, $(p-(a-p)/2,p+(a-p)/2)\cap(a,b]=\emptyset$, since $p+(a-p)/2=(a+p)/2<a$. Thus $p$ is not a limit point of $(a,b]$.
2. If $p=a$, for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, $a+\epsilon/2\in(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)\cap(a,b]$, so $(p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)\cap(a,b]\neq\emptyset$. This proves that $p=a$ is a limit point of $(a,b]$.
3. If $p\in(a,b]$, it is trivial that $p$ is a limit point of $(a,b]$.
4. If $p>b$, $(a,b]\cap(p-(p-b)/2,p+(p-b/2)=\emptyset$, since $b<p-(p-b)/2$. Thus $p$ is not a limit point of $(a,b]$.

Threfore we conclude: the closure of $(a,b]$ is $[a,b]$.